# Можно ли дописать в существующий xls файл данные?

Tags: javascript, java

Ребят такой вопрос, есть `JavaScript` который делает экспорт `html` таблицы в `xls` файл, но есть проблема, запрос получения данных построен так что на странице выводятся не все данные, сделана пагинация с помощью `limit offset`, то есть экспорт идет текущей страницы с текущими данными, потом я перехожу на вторую страницу и оно делает экспорт со второй страницы в новый файл, собственно вопрос, можно ли как-то дописать данные со второй страницы в файл который уже создан после экспорта первой страницы?

Вот скрипт:

```
function fnExcelReport5()
{
    var tab_text = "<table border='2px'><tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>";

    var j = 0;
    tab = document.getElementById('tableList'); // id of table

    for (j = 2; j < tab.rows.length; j++)
    {
        tab_text = tab_text + tab.rows[j].innerHTML + "</tr>";

    }

    tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, "");
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, "");

    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,';
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var d = new Date();
    var mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
    a.setAttribute("href", uri + '\uFEFF' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
    a.setAttribute('download', "CSXL07010_" +
            d.getDate() + "." +
            mm + "." +
            d.getFullYear() + "_" +
            d.getHours() + "." +
            d.getMinutes() + "." +
            d.getSeconds() + '.xls');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
}
fnExcelReport5();
```

Сервлет:

```
List<Skisql> skisqlS = new ArrayList<Skisql>();

        try { 
            String nzak = request.getParameter("nzak").replace("*", "%").toUpperCase();

            String kiz = request.getParameter("kiz").replace("*", "%").toUpperCase();

            String osd = request.getParameter("osd").replace("*", "%").toUpperCase();

            String pri = request.getParameter("pri");

            String naim = request.getParameter("naim").replace("*", "%").toUpperCase();

            int page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
            int count = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("count"));

            Integer pages;
            try {
                pages = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pages"));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                pages = 25;
            }

            // int pages = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pages"));
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "select nzak, kiz, osd_t,(osd_c||osd_r) as osd, pri, naim "
                    + "from clippersql.skisql "
                    + "where nzak like '" + nzak + "%'"
                    + " and kiz like '" + kiz + "%'"
                    + " and osd_c||osd_r like '" + osd + "%'"
                    + " and CAST(pri AS text) like '" + pri + "%'"
                    + " and naim like '" + naim + "%'"
                    + " order by  nzak, pri, kiz "
                    + " limit " + pages + " offset " + count
            );

            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Skisql skisql = new Skisql();

                skisql.setNzak(rs.getString("nzak"));
                skisql.setKiz(rs.getString("kiz"));
                skisql.setOsd(rs.getString("osd"));
                skisql.setPri(rs.getString("pri"));
                skisql.setNaim(rs.getString("naim"));

                skisqlS.add(skisql);
            }

            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/searchViewSki.jsp");

            int size = skisqlS.size();
            request.setAttribute("page", page);
            request.setAttribute("osd", osd.replace("%", "*"));
            request.setAttribute("nzak", nzak.replace("%", "*"));
            request.setAttribute("kiz", kiz.replace("%", "*"));

            request.setAttribute("pri", pri);
            request.setAttribute("naim", naim);
            request.setAttribute("size", size);
            int counts = 1000;
            request.setAttribute("counts", counts);
            request.setAttribute("count", count);
            request.setAttribute("pages", pages);

            request.setAttribute("skisqlS", skisqlS);
            view.forward(request, response);
```

JSP страница:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/exportExcel_Ski.js"></script>

 <form  class=" form-inline searchTmi pull-left" style="padding-right: 5px;" method="get" name="frm" action="SearchSki">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Номер замовлення</label> <input type="text" size="10px" name="nzak" value="${nzak}" id="nzak" align="middle" placeholder="Номер">
                            </div>

                            <input type="hidden" name="page" id="page" value="1">

                            <input type="hidden" name="count" id="count" value="0">

                            <input class="rawOnpage" type="hidden" name="pages" value="${pages}">

                            <!--Выполнить фильтр-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button id="filtAccept" class="btnCollor btn  btn-md btn-success" 
                                        data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Виконати фільтр">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>

                            <!--Удалить фильтр-->
                                <a href="SearchSki?page=1&count=0&nzak=&kiz=&osd=&pri=&naim=&pages=${pages}">
                                    <button type="button" class="btnCollor btn  btn-md btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Відмінити фільтр">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></a>
                            </div>

                        </form>
 <ul class="pagination">
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${page == 1}"><li><a class="disabled" href="SearchSki?page=1&count=0&nzak=${nzak}&kiz=${kiz}&osd=${osd}&pri=${pri}&naim=${naim}&pages=${pages}">Перша</a></li></c:when> 
                        <c:otherwise><li><a class="a2" href="SearchSki?page=1&count=0&nzak=${nzak}&kiz=${kiz}&osd=${osd}&pri=${pri}&naim=${naim}&pages=${pages}">Перша</a></li></c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>

                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${page <=1}"><li class="li1"><a class="disabled" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Назад" href="SearchSki?page=${page-1}&count=${count-pages}&nzak=${nzak}&kiz=${kiz}&osd=${osd}&pri=${pri}&naim=${naim}&pages=${pages}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a></li></c:when> 
                        <c:otherwise><li class="li1"><a class="a2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Назад" href="SearchSki?page=${page-1}&count=${count-pages}&nzak=${nzak}&kiz=${kiz}&osd=${osd}&pri=${pri}&naim=${naim}&pages=${pages}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a></li></c:otherwise> 
                            </c:choose>

                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${size < pages}"><li class="li1"><a class="disabled" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Вперед" href="SearchSki?page=${page+1}&count=${count+pages}&nzak=${nzak}&kiz=${kiz}&osd=${osd}&pri=${pri}&naim=${naim}&pages=${pages}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a></li></c:when> 
                        <c:otherwise><li><a class="a2" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Вперед" href="SearchSki?page=${page+1}&count=${count+pages}&nzak=${nzak}&kiz=${kiz}&osd=${osd}&pri=${pri}&naim=${naim}&pages=${pages}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a></li></c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose>

                    <li><button id="excel2" class=" btnCollor btn btn-success btn-md" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="XLS-файл.Експорт поточної сторінки" onclick="fnExcelReport5();"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span></button></li>
                </ul>

<table border=1 id="tableList" class="table table-striped table-bordered" acceptCharset="UTF-8">
                <thead id="backgroundSearchHead">

                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="2">Номер <br>замовлення</th>
                        <th colspan="4">Виріб</th>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th>Код</th>
                        <th>Позначення</th>
                        <th>Пріоритет</th>
                        <th>Найменування</th>
                    </tr>

                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${not empty skisqlS}">
                            <c:forEach items="${skisqlS}" var="skisql" >
                                <tr paint>

                                    <td>
                                        <c:out value="${skisql.nzak}" />
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <c:out value="${skisql.kiz}" />
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <c:out value="${skisql.osd}" /> 
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <c:out value="${skisql.pri}" /> 
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <c:out value="${skisql.naim}" /> 
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <tr paint>
                                <td colspan="5" align="center">Інформація за вказаним контекстом відсутня</td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>            
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Может данные с последующей страницы можно записывать в новый лист того же файла?

Comment: Судя по коду, вы создаете файл, потом его скачиваете! Естественно добавить в него уже нельзя. Можно по другому, сначала запросите все нужные данные и только потом создавайте файл.

Comment: как это можно реализовать? это единственный вариант который у меня получился, но он не подходит, подходит только если выборка вся помещается на одну страницу

Comment: Сложно ответить точно, не видя, каким образом у вас запрашиваются данные. Но общий принцип таков. Сначала запрашиваете все данные, потом создаете файл. Если хотите получить ответ, то приведите код, с помощью которого запрашиваете данные.

Comment: добавил код сервлета, на странице с помощью jstl выдаю данные в таблицу

Comment: при каждом переходе на новую страницу, заново выполняется запрос с новыми значениями переменных `limit` и `offset`

Comment: Извините, я чуть чуть не точно выразился. Интересует код на стороне клиента, которым вы запрашиваете данные и отрисовываете таблицу. Или у вас на стороне сервера генерируется страница?

Comment: добавил код  jsp страницы

Answer (score 2):

Я вижу только один вариант.

Сделать сервлет, который будет отдавать весь набор данных, сделать к нему `AJAX` запрос, потом сделать файл. Или на сервере генерировать файл, что может быть хуже\лучше - это зависит от данных.

Поскольку страница гененрируется на сервере, то очень сложно будет получить все данные. Можно, конечно, использовать браузерный `WebSQL` или `Local Storage`, но можно столкнуться с ограничениями по памяти.

Comment: думал по этому поводу, но есть проблема, есть БД где хранится 6 миллионов записей, и это будет очень долгий процесс

Comment: Ну он в любом случае будет долгий. Вам нужно все 6 млн вывести в файл?

Comment: @СергейНиконенко А вообще, такие важные подробности надо в вопросе укзывать))

Comment: тут зависит от пользователя, он может делать как выборку данных, так и может нажать на кнопку и без фильтра))

Comment: спасибо за советы, буду что-то думать

Comment: @СергейНиконенко Если данные исторические, например, за прошеддшее время, и пользователей много, то имеет смысл генерировать файлы на сервере, сохранять их, отдавать пользователю. При поступлении такого же запроса - отдавать ранее сгенерированный файл.